# How to locate & select date from ng-model datepicker in Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am able to click and open the date picker pop up calendar but unable to select a particular date from it. Since the input field is read only, the input given through `sendkeys` or `JavascriptExecutor` is not accepted as valid input.

**Selenium Webdriver code:**
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/form/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[5]/div[1]/div/span/button")).click();
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].value = '02/08/2017'", driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='RunDate']")));

```html
<div class="input-group margin-bottom-5">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control ng-valid ng-isolate-scope ng-valid-date ng-dirty ng-touched" uib-datepicker-popup="MM/dd/yyyy" ng-readonly="true" name="RunDate" ng-model="jobModel.RunDate" ng-change="runDateChanged(jobModel.RunDate)" is-open="datepickers.RunDate" datepicker-options="dateOptions" show-button-bar="false" placeholder="Run Date" close-text="Close" readonly="readonly"><!-- ngIf: isOpen --><ul class="dropdown-menu ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-scope ng-valid-date-disabled" dropdown-nested="" ng-if="isOpen" style="display: block; top: 34px; left: 0px;" ng-style="{top: position.top+'px', left: position.left+'px'}" ng-keydown="keydown($event)" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()" uib-datepicker-popup-wrap="" ng-model="date" ng-change="dateSelection(date)" template-url="template/datepicker/popup.html">
 <li ng-transclude=""><div ng-switch="datepickerMode" role="application" ng-keydown="keydown($event)" uib-datepicker="" template-url="template/datepicker/datepicker.html" year-format="'yy'" starting-day="1" class="ng-isolate-scope">
  <!-- ngSwitchWhen: day --><table role="grid" aria-labelledby="datepicker-337-7387-title" aria-activedescendant="datepicker-337-7387-2" ng-switch-when="day" tabindex="0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-left" ng-click="move(-1)" tabindex="-1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></button></th>
      <th colspan="6"><button id="datepicker-337-7387-title" role="heading" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="toggleMode()" ng-disabled="datepickerMode === maxMode" tabindex="-1" style="width:100%;"><strong class="ng-binding">March 2017</strong></button></th>
      <th><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right" ng-click="move(1)" tabindex="-1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></button></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <!-- ngIf: showWeeks --><th ng-if="showWeeks" class="text-center ng-scope"></th><!-- end ngIf: showWeeks -->
      <!-- ngRepeat: label in ::labels track by $index --><th ng-repeat="label in ::labels track by $index" class="text-center ng-scope"><small aria-label="Monday" class="ng-binding">Mon</small></th><!-- end ngRepeat: label in ::labels track by $index --><th ng-repeat="label in ::labels track by $index" class="text-center ng-scope"><small aria-label="Tuesday" class="ng-binding">Tue</small></th><!-- end ngRepeat: label in ::labels track by $index --><th ng-repeat="label in ::labels track by $index" class="text-center ng-scope"><small aria-label="Wednesday" class="ng-binding">Wed</small></th><!-- end ngRepeat: label in ::labels track by $index --><th ng-repeat="label in ::labels track by $index" class="text-center ng-scope"><small aria-label="Thursday" class="ng-binding">Thu</small></th><!-- end ngRepeat: label in ::labels track by $index --><th ng-repeat="label in ::labels track by $index" class="text-center ng-scope"><small aria-label="Friday" class="ng-binding">Fri</small></th><!-- end ngRepeat: label in ::labels track by $index --><th ng-repeat="label in ::labels track by $index" class="text-center ng-scope"><small aria-label="Saturday" class="ng-binding">Sat</small></th><!-- end ngRepeat: label in ::labels track by $index --><th ng-repeat="label in ::labels track by $index" class="text-center ng-scope"><small aria-label="Sunday" class="ng-binding">Sun</small></th><!-- end ngRepeat: label in ::labels track by $index -->
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <!-- ngRepeat: row in rows track by $index --><tr ng-repeat="row in rows track by $index" class="ng-scope">
      <!-- ngIf: showWeeks --><td ng-if="showWeeks" class="text-center h6 ng-scope"><em class="ng-binding">9</em></td><!-- end ngIf: showWeeks -->
      <!-- ngRepeat: dt in row track by dt.date --><td ng-repeat="dt in row track by dt.date" class="text-center ng-scope" role="gridcell" id="datepicker-337-7387-0" ng-class="::dt.customClass">
        <button type="button" style="min-width:100%;" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-class="{'btn-info': dt.selected, active: isActive(dt)}" ng-click="select(dt.date)" ng-disabled="dt.disabled" tabindex="-1"><span ng-class="::{'text-muted': dt.secondary, 'text-info': dt.current}" class="ng-binding text-muted">27</span></button>
      </td><!-- end ngRepeat: dt in row track by dt.date --><td ng-repeat="dt in row track by dt.date" class="text-center ng-scope" role="gridcell" id="datepicker-337-7387-1" ng-class="::dt.customClass">
        <button type="button" style="min-width:100%;" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-class="{'btn-info': dt.selected, active: isActive(dt)}" ng-click="select(dt.date)" ng-disabled="dt.disabled" tabindex="-1"><span ng-class="::{'text-muted': dt.secondary, 'text-info': dt.current}" class="ng-binding text-muted">28</span></button>
      </td><!-- end ngRepeat: dt in row track by dt.date --><td ng-repeat="dt in row track by dt.date" class="text-center ng-scope" role="gridcell" id="datepicker-337-7387-2" ng-class="::dt.customClass">
        <button type="button" style="min-width:100%;" class="btn btn-default btn-sm active" ng-class="{'btn-info': dt.selected, active: isActive(dt)}" ng-click="select(dt.date)" ng-disabled="dt.disabled" tabindex="-1"><span ng-class="::{'text-muted': dt.secondary, 'text-info': dt.current}" class="ng-binding">01</span></button>
      </td><!-- end ngRepeat: dt in row track by dt.date --><td ng-repeat="dt in row track by dt.date" class="text-center ng-scope" role="gridcell" id="datepicker-337-7387-3" ng-class="::dt.customClass">
        <button type="button" style="min-width:100%;" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-class="{'btn-info': dt.selected, active: isActive(dt)}" ng-click="select(dt.date)" ng-disabled="dt.disabled" tabindex="-1"><span ng-class="::{'text-muted': dt.secondary, 'text-info': dt.current}" class="ng-binding">02</span></button>
      </td><!-- end ngRepeat: dt in row track by dt.date --><td ng-repeat="dt in row track by dt.date" class="text-center ng-scope" role="gridcell" id="datepicker-337-7387-4" ng-class="::dt.customClass">
        <button type="button" style="min-width:100%;" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-class="{'btn-info': dt.selected, active: isActive(dt)}" ng-click="select(dt.date)" ng-disabled="dt.disabled" tabindex="-1"><span ng-class="::{'text-muted': dt.secondary, 'text-info': dt.current}" class="ng-binding">03</span></button>
      </td><!-- end ngRepeat: dt in row track by dt.date --><td ng-repeat="dt in row track by dt.date" class="text-center ng-scope" role="gridcell" id="datepicker-337-7387-5" ng-class="::dt.customClass">
        <button type="button" style="min-width:100%;" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-class="{'btn-info': dt.selected, active: isActive(dt)}" ng-click="select(dt.date)" ng-disabled="dt.disabled" tabindex="-1"><span ng-class="::{'text-muted': dt.secondary, 'text-info': dt.current}" class="ng-binding">04</span></button>
      </td><!-- end ngRepeat: dt in row track by dt.date --><td ng-repeat="dt in row track by dt.date" class="text-center ng-scope" role="gridcell" id="datepicker-337-7387-6" ng-class="::dt.customClass">
        <button type="button" style="min-width:100%;" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-class="{'btn-info': dt.selected, active: isActive(dt)}" ng-click="select(dt.date)" ng-disabled="dt.disabled" tabindex="-1"><span ng-class="::{'text-muted': dt.secondary, 'text-info': dt.current}" class="ng-binding">05</span></button>
      </td><!-- end ngRepeat: dt in row track by dt.date -->
    </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: row in rows track by $index --><tr ng-repeat="row in rows track by $index" class="ng-scope">
      <!-- ngIf: showWeeks --><td ng-if="showWeeks" class="text-center h6 ng-scope"><em class="ng-binding">10</em></td><!-- end ngIf: showWeeks -->
      <!-- ngRepeat: dt in row track by dt.date --><td ng-repeat="dt in row track by dt.date" class="text-center ng-scope" role="gridcell" id="datepicker-337-7387-7" ng-class="::dt.customClass">
        <button type="button" style="min-width:100%;" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-class="{'btn-info': dt.selected, active: isActive(dt)}" ng-click="select(dt.date)" ng-disabled="dt.disabled" tabindex="-1"><span ng-class="::{'text-muted': dt.secondary, 'text-info': dt.current}" class="ng-binding">06</span></button>
      </td><!-- end ngRepeat: dt in row track by dt.date --><td ng-repeat="dt in row track by dt.date" class="text-center ng-scope" role="gridcell" id="datepicker-337-7387-8" ng-class="::dt.customClass">
        <button type="button" style="min-width:100%;" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-class="{'btn-info': dt.selected, active: isActive(dt)}" ng-click="select(dt.date)" ng-disabled="dt.disabled" tabindex="-1"><span ng-class="::{'text-muted': dt.secondary, 'text-info': dt.current}" class="ng-binding text-info">07</span></button>
      </td><!-- end ngRepeat: dt in row track by dt.date --><td ng-repeat="dt in row track by dt.date" class="text-center ng-scope" role="gridcell" id="datepicker-337-7387-9" ng-class="::dt.customClass">
        <button type="button" style="min-width:100%;" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-class="{'btn-info': dt.selected, active: isActive(dt)}" ng-click="select(dt.date)" ng-disabled="dt.disabled" tabindex="-1"><span ng-class="::{'text-muted': dt.secondary, 'text-info': dt.current}" class="ng-binding">08</span></button>
      </td><!-- end ngRepeat: dt in row track by dt.date --><td ng-repeat="dt in row track by dt.date" class="text-center ng-scope" role="gridcell" id="datepicker-337-7387-10" ng-class="::dt.customClass">
        <button type="button" style="min-width:100%;" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-class="{'btn-info': dt.selected, active: isActive(dt)}" ng-click="select(dt.date)" ng-disabled="dt.disabled" tabindex="-1"><span ng-class="::{'text-muted': dt.secondary, 'text-info': dt.current}" class="ng-binding">09</span></button>
      </td><!-- end ngRepeat: dt in row track by dt.date --><td ng-repeat="dt in row track by dt.date" class="text-center ng-scope" role="gridcell" id="datepicker-337-7387-11" ng-class="::dt.customClass">
        <button type="button" style="min-width:100%;" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-class="{'btn-info': dt.selected, active: isActive(dt)}" ng-click="select(dt.date)" ng-disabled="dt.disabled" tabindex="-1"><span ng-class="::{'text-muted': dt.secondary, 'text-info': dt.current}" class="ng-binding">10</span></button>
      </td><!-- end ngRepeat: dt in row track by dt.date --><td ng-repeat="dt in row track by dt.date" class="text-center ng-scope" role="gridcell" id="datepicker-337-7387-12" ng-class="::dt.customClass">
        <button type="button" style="min-width:100%;" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-class="{'btn-info': dt.selected, active: isActive(dt)}" ng-click="select(dt.date)" ng-disabled="dt.disabled" tabindex="-1"><span ng-class="::{'text-muted': dt.secondary, 'text-info': dt.current}" class="ng-binding">11</span></button>
      </td><!-- end ngRepeat: dt in row track by dt.date --><td ng-repeat="dt in row track by dt.date" class="text-center ng-scope" role="gridcell" id="datepicker-337-7387-13" ng-class="::dt.customClass">
        <button type="button" style="min-width:100%;" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-class="{'btn-info': dt.selected, active: isActive(dt)}" ng-click="select(dt.date)" ng-disabled="dt.disabled" tabindex="-1"><span ng-class="::{'text-muted': dt.secondary, 'text-info': dt.current}" class="ng-binding">12</span></button>
      </td><!-- end ngRepeat: dt in row track by dt.date -->
    </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: row in rows track by $index --><tr ng-repeat="row in rows track by $index" class="ng-scope">
      <!-- ngIf: showWeeks --><td ng-if="showWeeks" class="text-center h6 ng-scope"><em class="ng-binding">11</em></td><!-- end ngIf: showWeeks -->
      <!-- ngRepeat: dt in row track by dt.date --><td ng-repeat="dt in row track by dt.date" class="text-center ng-scope" role="gridcell" id="datepicker-337-7387-14" ng-class="::dt.customClass">
        <button type="button" style="min-width:100%;" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-class="{'btn-info': dt.selected, active: isActive(dt)}" ng-click="select(dt.date)" ng-disabled="dt.disabled" tabindex="-1"><span ng-class="::{'text-muted': dt.secondary, 'text-info': dt.current}" class="ng-binding">13</span></button>
      </td><!-- end ngRepeat: dt in row track by dt.date --><td ng-repeat="dt in row track by dt.date" class="text-center ng-scope" role="gridcell" id="datepicker-337-7387-15" ng-class="::dt.customClass">
        <button type="button" style="min-width:100%;" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-class="{'btn-info': dt.selected, active: isActive(dt)}" ng-click="select(dt.date)" ng-disabled="dt.disabled" tabindex="-1"><span ng-class="::{'text-muted': dt.secondary, 'text-info': dt.current}" class="ng-binding">14</span></button>
      </td><!-- end ngRepeat: dt in row track by dt.date --><td ng-repeat="dt in row track by dt.date" class="text-center ng-scope" role="gridcell" id="datepicker-337-7387-16" ng-class="::dt.customClass">
        <button type="button" style="min-width:100%;" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-class="{'btn-info': dt.selected, active: isActive(dt)}" ng-click="select(dt.date)" ng-disabled="dt.disabled" tabindex="-1"><span ng-class="::{'text-muted': dt.secondary, 'text-info': dt.current}" class="ng-binding">15</span></button>
      </td><!-- end ngRepeat: dt in row track by dt.date --><td ng-repeat="dt in row track by dt.date" class="text-center ng-scope" role="gridcell" id="datepicker-337-7387-17" ng-class="::dt.customClass">
        <button type="button" style="min-width:100%;" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-class="{'btn-info': dt.selected, active: isActive(dt)}" ng-click="select(dt.date)" ng-disabled="dt.disabled" tabindex="-1"><span ng-class="::{'text-muted': dt.secondary, 'text-info': dt.current}" class="ng-binding">16</span></button>
      </td><!-- end ngRepeat: dt in row track by dt.date --><td ng-repeat="dt in row track by dt.date" class="text-center ng-scope" role="gridcell" id="datepicker-337-7387-18" ng-class="::dt.customClass">
        <button type="button" style="min-width:100%;" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-class="{'btn-info': dt.selected, active: isActive(dt)}" ng-click="select(dt.date)" ng-disabled="dt.disabled" tabindex="-1"><span ng-class="::{'text-muted': dt.secondary, 'text-info': dt.current}" class="ng-binding">17</span></button>
      </td><!-- end ngRepeat: dt in row track by dt.date --><td ng-repeat="dt in row track by dt.date" class="text-center ng-scope" role="gridcell" id="datepicker-337-7387-19" ng-class="::dt.customClass">
        <button type="button" style="min-width:100%;" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-class="{'btn-info': dt.selected, active: isActive(dt)}" ng-click="select(dt.date)" ng-disabled="dt.disabled" tabindex="-1"><span ng-class="::{'text-muted': dt.secondary, 'text-info': dt.current}" class="ng-binding">18</span></button>
      </td><!-- end ngRepeat: dt in row track by dt.date --><td ng-repeat="dt in row track by dt.date" class="text-center ng-scope" role="gridcell" id="datepicker-337-7387-20" ng-class="::dt.customClass">
        <button type="button" style="min-width:100%;" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-class="{'btn-info': dt.selected, active: isActive(dt)}" ng-click="select(dt.date)" ng-disabled="dt.disabled" tabindex="-1"><span ng-class="::{'text-muted': dt.secondary, 'text-info': dt.current}" class="ng-binding">19</span></button>
      </td><!-- end ngRepeat: dt in row track by dt.date -->
    </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: row in rows track by $index --><tr ng-repeat="row in rows track by $index" class="ng-scope">
      <!-- ngIf: showWeeks --><td ng-if="showWeeks" class="text-center h6 ng-scope"><em class="ng-binding">12</em></td><!-- end ngIf: showWeeks -->
      <!-- ngRepeat: dt in row track by dt.date --><td ng-repeat="dt in row track by dt.date" class="text-center ng-scope" role="gridcell" id="datepicker-337-7387-21" ng-class="::dt.customClass">
        <button type="button" style="min-width:100%;" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-class="{'btn-info': dt.selected, active: isActive(dt)}" ng-click="select(dt.date)" ng-disabled="dt.disabled" tabindex="-1"><span ng-class="::{'text-muted': dt.secondary, 'text-info': dt.current}" class="ng-binding">20</span></button>
      </td><!-- end ngRepeat: dt in row track by dt.date --><td ng-repeat="dt in row track by dt.date" class="text-center ng-scope" role="gridcell" id="datepicker-337-7387-22" ng-class="::dt.customClass">
        <button type="button" style="min-width:100%;" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-class="{'btn-info': dt.selected, active: isActive(dt)}" ng-click="select(dt.date)" ng-disabled="dt.disabled" tabindex="-1"><span ng-class="::{'text-muted': dt.secondary, 'text-info': dt.current}" class="ng-binding">21</span></button>
      </td><!-- end ngRepeat: dt in row track by dt.date --><td ng-repeat="dt in row track by dt.date" class="text-center ng-scope" role="gridcell" id="datepicker-337-7387-23" ng-class="::dt.customClass">
        <button type="button" style="min-width:100%;" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-class="{'btn-info': dt.selected, active: isActive(dt)}" ng-click="select(dt.date)" ng-disabled="dt.disabled" tabindex="-1"><span ng-class="::{'text-muted': dt.secondary, 'text-info': dt.current}" class="ng-binding">22</span></button>
      </td><!-- end ngRepeat: dt in row track by dt.date --><td ng-repeat="dt in row track by dt.date" class="text-center ng-scope" role="gridcell" id="datepicker-337-7387-24" ng-class="::dt.customClass">
        <button type="button" style="min-width:100%;" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-class="{'btn-info': dt.selected, active: isActive(dt)}" ng-click="select(dt.date)" ng-disabled="dt.disabled" tabindex="-1"><span ng-class="::{'text-muted': dt.secondary, 'text-info': dt.current}" class="ng-binding">23</span></button>
      </td><!-- end ngRepeat: dt in row track by dt.date --><td ng-repeat="dt in row track by dt.date" class="text-center ng-scope" role="gridcell" id="datepicker-337-7387-25" ng-class="::dt.customClass">
        <button type="button" style="min-width:100%;" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-class="{'btn-info': dt.selected, active: isActive(dt)}" ng-click="select(dt.date)" ng-disabled="dt.disabled" tabindex="-1"><span ng-class="::{'text-muted': dt.secondary, 'text-info': dt.current}" class="ng-binding">24</span></button>
      </td><!-- end ngRepeat: dt in row track by dt.date --><td ng-repeat="dt in row track by dt.date" class="text-center ng-scope" role="gridcell" id="datepicker-337-7387-26" ng-class="::dt.customClass">
        <button type="button" style="min-width:100%;" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-class="{'btn-info': dt.selected, active: isActive(dt)}" ng-click="select(dt.date)" ng-disabled="dt.disabled" tabindex="-1"><span ng-class="::{'text-muted': dt.secondary, 'text-info': dt.current}" class="ng-binding">25</span></button>
      </td><!-- end ngRepeat: dt in row track by dt.date --><td ng-repeat="dt in row track by dt.date" class="text-center ng-scope" role="gridcell" id="datepicker-337-7387-27" ng-class="::dt.customClass">
        <button type="button" style="min-width:100%;" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-class="{'btn-info': dt.selected, active: isActive(dt)}" ng-click="select(dt.date)" ng-disabled="dt.disabled" tabindex="-1"><span ng-class="::{'text-muted': dt.secondary, 'text-info': dt.current}" class="ng-binding">26</span></button>
      </td><!-- end ngRepeat: dt in row track by dt.date -->
    </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: row in rows track by $index --><tr ng-repeat="row in rows track by $index" class="ng-scope">
      <!-- ngIf: showWeeks --><td ng-if="showWeeks" class="text-center h6 ng-scope"><em class="ng-binding">13</em></td><!-- end ngIf: showWeeks -->
      <!-- ngRepeat: dt in row track by dt.date --><td ng-repeat="dt in row track by dt.date" class="text-center ng-scope" role="gridcell" id="datepicker-337-7387-28" ng-class="::dt.customClass">
        <button type="button" style="min-width:100%;" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-class="{'btn-info': dt.selected, active: isActive(dt)}" ng-click="select(dt.date)" ng-disabled="dt.disabled" tabindex="-1"><span ng-class="::{'text-muted': dt.secondary, 'text-info': dt.current}" class="ng-binding">27</span></button>
      </td><!-- end ngRepeat: dt in row track by dt.date --><td ng-repeat="dt in row track by dt.date" class="text-center ng-scope" role="gridcell" id="datepicker-337-7387-29" ng-class="::dt.customClass">
        <button type="button" style="min-width:100%;" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-class="{'btn-info': dt.selected, active: isActive(dt)}" ng-click="select(dt.date)" ng-disabled="dt.disabled" tabindex="-1"><span ng-class="::{'text-muted': dt.secondary, 'text-info': dt.current}" class="ng-binding">28</span></button>
      </td><!-- end ngRepeat: dt in row track by dt.date --><td ng-repeat="dt in row track by dt.date" class="text-center ng-scope" role="gridcell" id="datepicker-337-7387-30" ng-class="::dt.customClass">
        <button type="button" style="min-width:100%;" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-class="{'btn-info': dt.selected, active: isActive(dt)}" ng-click="select(dt.date)" ng-disabled="dt.disabled" tabindex="-1"><span ng-class="::{'text-muted': dt.secondary, 'text-info': dt.current}" class="ng-binding">29</span></button>
      </td><!-- end ngRepeat: dt in row track by dt.date --><td ng-repeat="dt in row track by dt.date" class="text-center ng-scope" role="gridcell" id="datepicker-337-7387-31" ng-class="::dt.customClass">
        <button type="button" style="min-width:100%;" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-class="{'btn-info': dt.selected, active: isActive(dt)}" ng-click="select(dt.date)" ng-disabled="dt.disabled" tabindex="-1"><span ng-class="::{'text-muted': dt.secondary, 'text-info': dt.current}" class="ng-binding">30</span></button>
      </td><!-- end ngRepeat: dt in row track by dt.date --><td ng-repeat="dt in row track by dt.date" class="text-center ng-scope" role="gridcell" id="datepicker-337-7387-32" ng-class="::dt.customClass">
        <button type="button" style="min-width:100%;" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-class="{'btn-info': dt.selected, active: isActive(dt)}" ng-click="select(dt.date)" ng-disabled="dt.disabled" tabindex="-1"><span ng-class="::{'text-muted': dt.secondary, 'text-info': dt.current}" class="ng-binding">31</span></button>
      </td><!-- end ngRepeat: dt in row track by dt.date --><td ng-repeat="dt in row track by dt.date" class="text-center ng-scope" role="gridcell" id="datepicker-337-7387-33" ng-class="::dt.customClass">
        <button type="button" style="min-width:100%;" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-class="{'btn-info': dt.selected, active: isActive(dt)}" ng-click="select(dt.date)" ng-disabled="dt.disabled" tabindex="-1"><span ng-class="::{'text-muted': dt.secondary, 'text-info': dt.current}" class="ng-binding text-muted">01</span></button>
      </td><!-- end ngRepeat: dt in row track by dt.date --><td ng-repeat="dt in row track by dt.date" class="text-center ng-scope" role="gridcell" id="datepicker-337-7387-34" ng-class="::dt.customClass">
        <button type="button" style="min-width:100%;" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-class="{'btn-info': dt.selected, active: isActive(dt)}" ng-click="select(dt.date)" ng-disabled="dt.disabled" tabindex="-1"><span ng-class="::{'text-muted': dt.secondary, 'text-info': dt.current}" class="ng-binding text-muted">02</span></button>
      </td><!-- end ngRepeat: dt in row track by dt.date -->
    </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: row in rows track by $index --><tr ng-repeat="row in rows track by $index" class="ng-scope">
      <!-- ngIf: showWeeks --><td ng-if="showWeeks" class="text-center h6 ng-scope"><em class="ng-binding">14</em></td><!-- end ngIf: showWeeks -->
      <!-- ngRepeat: dt in row track by dt.date --><td ng-repeat="dt in row track by dt.date" class="text-center ng-scope" role="gridcell" id="datepicker-337-7387-35" ng-class="::dt.customClass">
        <button type="button" style="min-width:100%;" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-class="{'btn-info': dt.selected, active: isActive(dt)}" ng-click="select(dt.date)" ng-disabled="dt.disabled" tabindex="-1"><span ng-class="::{'text-muted': dt.secondary, 'text-info': dt.current}" class="ng-binding text-muted">03</span></button>
      </td><!-- end ngRepeat: dt in row track by dt.date --><td ng-repeat="dt in row track by dt.date" class="text-center ng-scope" role="gridcell" id="datepicker-337-7387-36" ng-class="::dt.customClass">
        <button type="button" style="min-width:100%;" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-class="{'btn-info': dt.selected, active: isActive(dt)}" ng-click="select(dt.date)" ng-disabled="dt.disabled" tabindex="-1"><span ng-class="::{'text-muted': dt.secondary, 'text-info': dt.current}" class="ng-binding text-muted">04</span></button>
      </td><!-- end ngRepeat: dt in row track by dt.date --><td ng-repeat="dt in row track by dt.date" class="text-center ng-scope" role="gridcell" id="datepicker-337-7387-37" ng-class="::dt.customClass">
        <button type="button" style="min-width:100%;" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-class="{'btn-info': dt.selected, active: isActive(dt)}" ng-click="select(dt.date)" ng-disabled="dt.disabled" tabindex="-1"><span ng-class="::{'text-muted': dt.secondary, 'text-info': dt.current}" class="ng-binding text-muted">05</span></button>
      </td><!-- end ngRepeat: dt in row track by dt.date --><td ng-repeat="dt in row track by dt.date" class="text-center ng-scope" role="gridcell" id="datepicker-337-7387-38" ng-class="::dt.customClass">
        <button type="button" style="min-width:100%;" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-class="{'btn-info': dt.selected, active: isActive(dt)}" ng-click="select(dt.date)" ng-disabled="dt.disabled" tabindex="-1"><span ng-class="::{'text-muted': dt.secondary, 'text-info': dt.current}" class="ng-binding text-muted">06</span></button>
      </td><!-- end ngRepeat: dt in row track by dt.date --><td ng-repeat="dt in row track by dt.date" class="text-center ng-scope" role="gridcell" id="datepicker-337-7387-39" ng-class="::dt.customClass">
        <button type="button" style="min-width:100%;" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-class="{'btn-info': dt.selected, active: isActive(dt)}" ng-click="select(dt.date)" ng-disabled="dt.disabled" tabindex="-1"><span ng-class="::{'text-muted': dt.secondary, 'text-info': dt.current}" class="ng-binding text-muted">07</span></button>
      </td><!-- end ngRepeat: dt in row track by dt.date --><td ng-repeat="dt in row track by dt.date" class="text-center ng-scope" role="gridcell" id="datepicker-337-7387-40" ng-class="::dt.customClass">
        <button type="button" style="min-width:100%;" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-class="{'btn-info': dt.selected, active: isActive(dt)}" ng-click="select(dt.date)" ng-disabled="dt.disabled" tabindex="-1"><span ng-class="::{'text-muted': dt.secondary, 'text-info': dt.current}" class="ng-binding text-muted">08</span></button>
      </td><!-- end ngRepeat: dt in row track by dt.date --><td ng-repeat="dt in row track by dt.date" class="text-center ng-scope" role="gridcell" id="datepicker-337-7387-41" ng-class="::dt.customClass">
        <button type="button" style="min-width:100%;" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-class="{'btn-info': dt.selected, active: isActive(dt)}" ng-click="select(dt.date)" ng-disabled="dt.disabled" tabindex="-1"><span ng-class="::{'text-muted': dt.secondary, 'text-info': dt.current}" class="ng-binding text-muted">09</span></button>
      </td><!-- end ngRepeat: dt in row track by dt.date -->
    </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: row in rows track by $index -->
  </tbody>
</table><!-- end ngSwitchWhen: -->
  <!-- ngSwitchWhen: month -->
  <!-- ngSwitchWhen: year -->
</div></li>
 <!-- ngIf: showButtonBar -->
</ul><!-- end ngIf: isOpen -->
                                                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                                                <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event,'RunDate','TrapDate,DownloadDate,FRDueDate,ReportDate')" ng-disabled="controlsDisabled">
                                                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
                                                                </button>
                                                            </span>
                                                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the `list` of Calendar table rows separately and through a `For each loop`for every table row locate the cells (date) through another `For Each loop` to pick the date. Find the code below.

`WebElement RunDateCalendar = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-default'][1]"));
        RunDateCalendar.click();`

```
    List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".ng-isolate-scope>table>tbody>tr"));
    int rowcount = elements.size();
    System.out.println("Number of Rows in Calendar = " +rowcount);
    outerloop:{
        for (WebElement webElement : elements) {
            List<WebElement> dates = webElement.findElements(By.cssSelector(".ng-isolate-scope>table>tbody>tr>td[id]"));
            for (WebElement click : dates) {
                if (click.getText().equals("13")) {
                    System.out.println("Selecting the Date");
                    click.click();
                    break outerloop;
                }
                System.out.println("End of Date Column Loop");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("End of Calendar Date Selection");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the date in your script by using sendKeys function for the date webelement in the required format which is been accepted by the date picker .

The date-picker has format of "MM/dd/yyyy" then you may use use the following code

```
WebElement date = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='RunDate']"));
date.sendKeys("03/13/2017");
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.
The solution did not work out as the **ng-calendar** itself a separate table html, only the values that are selected by the _click_ on the ng-calendar only is getting accepted into the field.

Comment: if you see the html code then you will see its an input field headed with the calender table. Try to use the above code as it is in your script where you need to validate the date functionality. I have written code seeing the html you have provided.

Comment: As you can see the input tag though its type=text, its a read only(bolded) field and hence inputs that are given either by using `send keys` r through `JavascriptExecutor` the webpage doesnot accept. 
<input type="text" class="form-control ng-valid ng-isolate-scope ng-valid-date ng-dirty ng-touched" uib-datepicker-popup="MM/dd/yyyy" **ng-readonly="true"** name="RunDate" ng-model="jobModel.RunDate" ng-change="runDateChanged(jobModel.RunDate)" is-open="datepickers.RunDate" datepicker-options="dateOptions" show-button-bar="false" placeholder="Run Date" close-text="Close" **readonly="readonly**">

Comment: Only the date which is clicked from the subsequent calendar is only accepted as valid input.